# Disable Javascript popups when using Windows.Forms.Webbrowser.Navigate()

Tags: .net, javascript, popup, webbrowser-control, console-application

Ok, I have a very frustrating problem. I am parsing a webpage and need to have it execute the javascript in order to get the information I want.

```
Form f = new Form();
WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
w.Navigate(url);
f.Controls.Add(w);
f.ShowDialog();
HtmlElementCollection hc = w.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
```

This works and I'm able to get the button elements fine, but then I get a popup everytime I run this. Very annoying. The popup is javascript based and I need to run Javascript to get the button element info. Here is the script for the popup.

```
<script>
var evilPopup = (getCookieVar("markOpen","PromoPop") == 1);
if (evilPopup != 1) 
{
    PromoPop = window.open('/browse/info.aspx?cid=36193','Advertisement', 'width=365,height=262,screenX=100,screenY=100');

if (PromoPop) 
    {
       PromoPop.blur();
       window.focus();
       setCookieVar("markOpen","PromoPop","1");             
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried in vane to possibly add a cookie to the Forms.Webbrowser control but got frustrated and gave up. I tried setting the NoAllowNavagate property and everything else to no avail.

Can anyone help? Also, there a way to get the DomDocument info from the Console.App without having to open a form?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WebBrowser component has NewWindow event with CancelEventArgs. So just add a handler similar to:

```
void webBrowser1_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

When the javascript tries to open a popup window the event gets triggered and cancels it.

Comment: Wow, I am going to try this out right now. This looks very promising and has the "duh" factor to it. 

Okay I just tested it out 15 times and it works great! A special place in my heart is now reserved for you kind stranger.

Answer (score 0):

Can you inject Javascript into the document?  You could add this:

```
window.open = function() { return false; }
```

Comment: I am really lame when it comes to Javascript. I didn't even realize your could inject Javascript. If that's the case, I might not even have to go the route I am going now. Thanks for your comment, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to use WebClient to download the html to a temporary file, replace the ad script with string.Empty and load the file in the control.

Comment: I tried this approach I think, I tried to load the html in Stream afterwards but didn't have any luck. I don't know I have to study WebClient further, I tried to do what you mentioned using HttpWebRequest/WebResponse. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should try SHDocVw.dll to automatically catch new window.

```
        private SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1 Web_V1;

        // write it on form load event

        Web_V1 = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser_V1)this.webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;

        Web_V1.NewWindow += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_NewWindowEventHandler(Web_V1_NewWindow);


        private void Web_V1_NewWindow(string URL, int Flags, string TargetFrameName, ref object PostData, string Headers, ref bool Processed)
        {
            Processed = true; //Stop event from being processed

            //Code to open in same window
            //this.webBrowser1.Navigate(URL);

            //Code to open in new window instead of same window
            frmEBeyanname Popup = new frmEBeyanname();
            Popup.webBrowser1.Navigate(URL);
            Popup.Show();
        }
```

bye